# Download Apps on loaned iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-id

Can I download some apps if Apple loans me an iPhone?

Apple is repairing my iPhone so they loaned me a device to use while mine is being repaired.

Answer (score 2):

Login with your AppleID in `Settings > iTunes and App Stores` and then run the App Store. Look in the `Updates > Purchased` tab for all the apps you can download.

In-app purchases can sometimes be re-enabled, but not all app developers handle this. Your milage may vary.

Make sure you go to `Settings > General > Reset` and Erase all Content and Settings before you turn in the loaner.